# Convert to CSV in a downloadable format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to convert an array of objects into CSV.

Please have a look at the code. What I am doing wrong? I am getting an array when I `console.log("csv",array)` which is passed from `printAccountsGa`. Moreover, I have declared `JSONGA = []` globally but still I get array with every object on consoling. But when I pass that to `csvConverter` function it displays `undefined`.

```
function printAccountsGa(results) {
  if (results && !results.error) {
    var accounts = results.items;
    for (var i = 0, account; account = accounts[i]; i++) {
      //console.log('Account Id: ' + account.id);
      listProperties(account.id);
      //console.log('Account Name: ' + account.name);
    }
    console.log(JSONGA);
    csvConverter(JSONGA);
  }
}

function printAccountsGtm(results) {
    console.log("result is",results);
    if (results && !results.error) {
    var accounts = results.accounts;
    console.log(accounts);
    for (var i = 0, account; account = accounts[i]; i++) {
      //console.log('Account Id: ' + account.accountId);
      listContainers(account.accountId);
      //console.log('Account Name: ' + account.name);
    }
  }
}

function listProperties(accountID){
  var request = gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties.list({
    'accountId': accountID
  });
  request.execute(printProperties);
}

function printProperties(results){
  if (results && !results.error) {
    var properties = results.items;
    //console.log(properties[0].accountId);
    $.each(properties,function(element){
      //console.log(properties[element].accountId);
      var tempObj={};
      tempObj={
        'AccountID':properties[element].accountId,
        'PropertyID':properties[element].id,
        'name':properties[element].name,
      }
      JSONGA.push(tempObj);
    })
 }
}






function csvConverter(array){
  console.log("csv",array);
   var result = array.map(function(d){
        return JSON.stringify(values(d));
    })
    .join('\n') 
    .replace(/(^\[)|(\]$)/mg, '');

  window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(result));
}


window.onload = function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('auth-button-ga');
  el.addEventListener('click', authorizeGa);
  var elt = document.getElementById("auth-button-gtm");
  elt.addEventListener('click', authorizeGtm);
}
```

Comment: can you please post question in simplest form, i.e. what is input data/array/json

Comment: Which server side language are you using? To provide a download, you should do it on server side.

Comment: Setting `Content-Disposition` to `'attachment;filename='{filename}'` and `Content-Type:"text/csv"` in response headers would automatically trigger a download on browser, so just parse on your server and send the response as a csv string.

Comment: @A.T Input is array of objects...which is the trouble maker I am sure that array contains the objects which should be converted to CSV.Even If I console log it shows me the data but I am not able to convert it to csv as it says it's undefined